# Passing Date as a Parameter took more time to execute the procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, procedure

I wrote a procedure to return a set of records for a report. If a date variable declared and assigned inside the procedure then it took 20 sec to execute and return the proper results. At the same time, date value passed as a parameter. It took more than 3 minutes (I have stopped the procedure execution).

1.Following procedure took only 20 sec to complete

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Month_OP_CL] 
AS
BEGIN   
  
    DECLARE @RptDate DATE = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE);
    SELECT .....
END;

EXEC [dbo].[Month_OP_CL];
```

2.Following procedure took more than 3 minutes to complete

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Month_OP_CL]  
(
    @RptDate DATE
)
AS
BEGIN   
   
 SELECT .....
END;


DECLARE @RptDate DATE = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE);
EXEC dbo.[Month_OP_CL] @RptDate.
```

Any mistakes?

Comment: [Parameter Sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/)

Comment: No Mistakes. As  mentioned by @Squirrel it is due to Parameter Sniffing. Assign the parameter value to a local variable, and change the queries in the SP to use the local variable rather than the parameter.

Comment: Noted. Thanks a lot